# HIVE left join on nearest date

Tags: date, hadoop, join, hive, hiveql

I am trying to join 2 tables in HIVE using a key and the nearest date in the 2 tables at the time of join. For example: Below are the 2 input tables

```
<----------TABLE A------------->            <------------TABLE B------------>
A_id    A_date      changed_col             B_id    B_date      B_value A_id
****    ******      ***********             ****    ******      ******* *****   
A01     2017-03-20      ABC                 B01     2017-04-02  200     A01
A01     2017-04-01      XYZ                 B01     2017-04-04  500     A01
A01     2017-04-05      LLL
```

However when I LEFT JOIN table B with Table A, it should look for the nearest lowest date in table A for the same key(A_id). Below is the expected output table:

```
B_id    B_date          A_id        A_date      changed col   B_value
****    ******          ****        ******      ***********   *******
B01     2017-02-04      A01     2017-01-04      XYZ             200
B01     2017-04-04      A01     2017-01-04      XYZ             500
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `2017-20-03`? is that how you keep dates?

Comment: for now I have used the format yyyy-dd-mm.

Comment: Not a good decision. Why not using date type?

Comment: ya any format is fine, as long as i get the output. I have corrected the date format too as yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: I have just added a scenario(with ids B02 and A02) where this query will not serve the purpose. The idea is that the record from Table B should match with the closest lowest date for the same id in Table A. Is it possible to handle this scenario using query alone? I am guessing a HIVE UDAF will solve this issue, but just wanted to know if is achievable through query too.

Comment: The whole point of an ID column is that it solely identifies the record. B_id should be unique (and so should be A_id in table A or any other ID column for that matter)

Comment: since storage in hive do not need to have a unique id, I can add 2 rows which have the same id, with any column value changes. My requirement is that now for the newly added row in B (B02     2017-04-07  900     A02) i should get (A02     2017-04-06      KKK) from A, **since the closest previous update for B02  2017-04-07 updated row happened on 2017-04-06 in table A**

Comment: Adding to my above comment, the point here is to get the nearest/closest previous updated record from A for an updated row in B and not the latest record.

Comment: Anna, please rollback your post to its original version and open a new question for this

Comment: Mark, I do not want to rollback, since the requirement was to get the nearest record from the beginning. However if its really necessary I can roll back.

Comment: It was a reasonable assumption that a column named B_id is unique and your original data sample matched this assumption. Since you did change the demo sample, making an ID column non-unique I think we should revert to the original scenario and open a new question for the new scenario.  P.s. The solution would be similar, with a little addition.

Comment: Sure not a problem. I have reverted back to the original dataset and have raised a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460773/hive-join-to-get-the-date-wise-picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  B.B_id
       ,B.B_date
       ,B.A_id
       ,A.A_date
       ,A.changed_col
       ,B_value

from                B

        left join  (select  *

                    from   (select  B.B_id
                                   ,A.A_date
                                   ,A.changed_col

                                   ,row_number () over
                                    (
                                        partition by    B.B_id
                                        order by        A.A_date desc
                                    ) as rn
                            from            B
                                    join    A
                                    on      A.A_id = B.A_id
                            where   A.A_date <= B.B_date 
                            ) A

                    where rn = 1
                    ) A

        on          A.B_id  =
                    B.B_id
```

---

```
+------+------------+------+------------+-------------+---------+
| b_id |   b_date   | a_id |   a_date   | changed_col | b_value |
+------+------------+------+------------+-------------+---------+
| B01  | 2017-04-02 | A01  | 2017-04-01 | XYZ         |     200 |
| B01  | 2017-04-04 | A01  | 2017-04-01 | XYZ         |     500 |
+------+------------+------+------------+-------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select  B_id
       ,dt                  as B_date
       ,A_id
       ,A_data.A_date       as A_date 
       ,A_data.changed_col
       ,B_value

from   (select  B_id,dt,B_value,A_id,tab               
               ,max 
                (   case 
                        when tab = 'A' 
                        then named_struct ('A_date',dt,'changed_col',changed_col) 
                    end
                ) over
                (
                    partition by    A_id
                    order by        dt,tab
                    rows            between unbounded preceding
                                    and     current row
                ) as A_data


        from   (select  B_id,B_date as dt,B_value,A_id
                       ,'B' as tab,null as changed_col
                from    B                

                union all

                select  null as B_id,A_date as dt,null as B_value,A_id
                       ,'A' as tab,changed_col
                from    A
                ) t
        ) t

where   tab = 'B'
```

---

```
+------+------------+------+------------+-------------+---------+
| b_id |   b_date   | a_id |   a_date   | changed_col | b_value |
+------+------------+------+------------+-------------+---------+
| B01  | 2017-04-02 | A01  | 2017-04-01 | XYZ         |     200 |
| B01  | 2017-04-04 | A01  | 2017-04-01 | XYZ         |     500 |
+------+------------+------+------------+-------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select  B.B_id
       ,B.B_date
       ,B.A_id
       ,A.A_data.A_date         as A_date 
       ,A.A_data.changed_col    as changed_col
       ,B_value

from                B

        left join  (select      B.B_id
                               ,max (named_struct ('A_date',A_date,'changed_col',changed_col)) as A_data

                    from                B
                                join    A
                                on      A.A_id = B.A_id

                    where       A.A_date <= B.B_date 

                    group by    B.B_id
                    ) A

        on          A.B_id  =
                    B.B_id
```

---

```
+------+------------+------+------------+-------------+---------+
| b_id |   b_date   | a_id |   a_date   | changed_col | b_value |
+------+------------+------+------------+-------------+---------+
| B01  | 2017-04-02 | A01  | 2017-04-01 | XYZ         |     200 |
| B01  | 2017-04-04 | A01  | 2017-04-01 | XYZ         |     500 |
+------+------------+------+------------+-------------+---------+
```

Comment: This seems like the cleanest solution

Comment: Works perfectly for this example and my specific case. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative is:

```
select B.B_id, B.B_date, B.A_id, A1.A_id, A1.A_date, A1.changed_col, B.B_value
from 
TABLE_B as B,
(
select A_id, A_date, chaged_col
from TABLE_A as A
where A_date = (select min(A_date) from TABLE_A where A_id = A.A_id) ) as A1
where B.A_id = A.A_id
```